# unable to click outside dialog and make changes to edittext

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I have a custom dialog with yes and no imageview which has setonclicklistner attached.The background is transparent and the layout is at the bottom.

now I would like to click on the edittext which exists in the background or MainActivity.At the same time I dont want dialog to disappear.I want to switch between dialog and edittext both existing at the sametime.Currently I used the style below and I would like to click on the edittext whixh exists behind the frame(Window) .
How do I do that.Please help me out.Ireally appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

Style used:

```
<style name="Custom2" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>


    </style>
```

MainActivity.class

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        final Context context = this;
        private Button button;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonShowCustomDialog);

            // add button listener
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // custom dialog
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.Custom2);
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);


            // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
            ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
          }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can do it with dialog you can implement it with a layout on other layout and can change focus between these two layout

Comment: Can you tell me more in detail .Should I use AlertDialog.Builder ?

Comment: you can't intract with your activity when dialog is open you should dismiss it till can intract with your activity.why you need thing same it.it isn't user friendly